# Mostrar un mensaje de error dentro de la pagina Login al poner mal la contraseña

Tags: python-3.x, aplicación-web, python-3.7

Estoy realizando un formulario dentro de un sitio web para registrarse y despues iniciar sesion
Tanto el registro como el inicio de sesion funcionan sin problemas, pero dentro del trabajo que debo hacer es que, cuando introduzca mal la contraseña en el Login, esta me mande un mensaje de error de que la contraseña esta incorrecta.
He encontrado algunas maneras de hacerlo pero cuando lo pruebo, la pagina se queda en blanco con el texto "none"
He aqui el codigo:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import web

web.config.debug = False

urls = (
    '/login', 'Login',
    '/signup', 'Signup',
    '/inicio', 'Inicio',
)

app =  web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('views')


class Login:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login() 
            
    def POST(self):
        import sys
        try:
            formulario = web.input()
            email = formulario.email
            password = formulario.password
            conn =  sql.connect('test.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            statement = f"SELECT * from USUARIOS WHERE EMAIL='{email}' AND PASSWORD='{password}'" #crea una variable donde se almacenara la consulta a la base de datos con los datos que ingresamos en el formulario
            cur.execute(statement) #ejecuta la consulta
            if cur.fetchone():#se comprueba el retorno de datos
                return web.seeother("inicio")#redirecciona a otra pagina web
        except Exception:
            print(sys.stderr, "Login Failed")
            return render.login("usuario incorrecto")



class Signup:
    def GET(self):
        return render.signup() 
            
    def POST(self):
        try:
            formulario = web.input()
            email = formulario.email
            password = formulario.password
            print("el correo es ", email, " y la contraseña es ", password)
            conn =  sql.connect('test.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            insertStat = f"INSERT INTO USUARIOS(EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES ('{email}', '{password}')"#crea una variable donde se almacenara la operacion de insertar a la base de datos con los datos que ingresamos en el formulario
            cur.execute(insertStat)
            conn.commit()#guardamos los dato que hemos ingresado
            statement = f"SELECT * from USUARIOS WHERE EMAIL='{email}' AND PASSWORD='{password}'"#crea una variable donde se almacenara la consulta a la base de datos con los datos que ingresamos en el formulario
            cur.execute(statement) #ejecuta la consulta
            if cur.fetchone():#se comprueba el retorno de datos
                return web.seeother("login")#redirecciona a otra pagina web
        except Exception:
            


class Inicio:
    def GET(self):
        return render.inicio() # renderiza a inicio.html
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

se supone que en el Except deberia de colocar para el error, pero las formas que he intentado o no suelen funcionarme o me manda a la misma pantalla con el none.

El html:

```html
$def with (message)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>$message</p>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="">CORREO</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <label for="">CONTRASEÑA</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```